# Find intersections of a general vector with zeros MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Consider a general vector which represent some non-linear function

for example:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
f = [-1 6 8 7 5 2 0.1 -2 -3];
```

Is there a method in matlab that can find the solutions of `f(x)=0`? with some given accuracy

Comment: You could interpolate and search of changes of sign? Something like `find( bool(sign(finterp) + 1) ) ,`

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, when you have a random distribution `f`, finding zeros can only be done with linear interpolation between the data points:

For your example, I would define a function `myFunc` as:

```
function y = myFunc(val)
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
f = [-1 6 8 7 5 2 0.1 -2 -3 3];
P = griddedInterpolant (x, f, 'linear', 'linear'); 
y = P(val);
end
```

and apply a root searching algorithm via something like `fzero`:

```
val = 0; 
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
x = [-inf x inf]; % Look outside boundary too
fun = @myFunc;
sol = zeros(1, numel(x)-1);
cnt = 0;
for i = 1:length(x)-1 % fzero stops at the 1st zero hence the loop over each interval
    bound = [x(i) x(i+1)];
    try 
        z = fzero(fun, bound);
        cnt = cnt+1;
        sol(cnt) = z;
    catch
        % No answer within the boundary
    end
end
sol(cnt+1:end) = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `interp1` in `arrayfun` like below (linear interpolation was adopted)

```
x0 = arrayfun(@(k) interp1(f(k:k+1),x(k:k+1),0),find(sign(f(1:end-1).*f(2:end))<0));
```

such that

```
x0 =

   1.1429   7.0476   9.5000
```

**DATA**

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
f = [-1 6 8 7 5 2 0.1 -2 -3 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a function that does it, but feel it is something quite "regular" that matlab must have built in answers...so if someone has any write it down and I will accept it as an answer.

```
function sol = find_zeros(x,f)    
    f_vec = round(f*10^2)/10^2;
    ind=find(diff(sign(f_vec))~=0);
    K = length(ind);
    if (K>0)
        sol = zeros(1,K);
        for k=1:K
            if (f_vec(ind(k))<f_vec(ind(k)+1))                
                df = f_vec(ind(k)):0.01:f_vec(ind(k)+1);
            else
                df = flip(f_vec(ind(k)+1):0.01:f_vec(ind(k)));
            end
            dx = linspace(x(ind(k)),x(ind(k)+1),length(df));
            j = find(df==0);
            sol(k) = dx(j);
        end
    else
        sol=[];
    end
    sol=unique(sol);
end
```

Comment: You can create a [problem structure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/create-a-problem-structure.html) and have an optimizer like `fzero` or `fslove` solve the problem. I think at the end of the day since you are dealing with a random vector rather than an equation it is probably going to be difficult to find a single function root finder that does the job.